# luarocks install fails?

Tags: lua, torch

I install torch following
http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html

But when I use luarocks to install libs, like itorch, I command

```
luarocks install itorch
```

gives

> Error: Your user does not have write permissions in
>   /home/myname/code/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks
>   -- you may want to run as a privileged user or use your local tree with --local.

Then I cmd

```
sudo luarocks install itorch
```

gives

> sudo: luarocks: command not found

Then I cmd

```
luarocks
```

gives

> Configuration files:
>   System: /home/myname/code/torch/install/etc/luarocks/config.lua (ok)
>   User  : /home/myname/.luarocks/config.lua **(not found)**
>   Rocks trees in use:
>   /home/myname/.luarocks
>   /home/myname/code/torch/install

So is it installed successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

The first error message explains the problem: your user doesn't have write permission to the directory where you installed Torch. This is probably because you ran something as root that you shouldn't have.

You can probably fix this by running something like:

```
sudo chown -R myname: /home/myname/code/torch/install/lib/luarocks
sudo chmod -R u+w /home/myname/code/torch/install/lib/luarocks
```